# Best way to programmatically remove a category/term from a post

Tags: custom-field, taxonomy, post-meta, api

I am working on a script to convert all posts in a given category to use a postmeta flag instead (testing of MySQL has shown me that on a site as large as mine this will lead to a meaningful decrease in query time).

When converting posts I want to just fetch all posts in the category, add the postmeta then remove the category, which will let me just reload that function until there are no more posts in the category.

I can't find a good function for removing a term from a post though. I want to give it the post id and the term taxonomy+ID and have it handled for me.

I am also interested in plugins that can do the conversion for me if anyone knows of one. I couldn't find any that did cat->postmeta, unlike the opposite which can be handled by Scribu's plugin.

Comment: Do you want to do it via the API, or is it OK to do this with SQL queries? It won't be too hard, just one query to insert the new postmeta values, one to remove the post-category relationships, and maybe one to update the category count.

Comment: I definitely want to use the API. Category counts etc. is not something I want to have to account for in this case. The wp_get_object_terms()/wp_set_object_terms() will already make it pretty easy to manipulate terms, but I was hoping for a one-function solution from core.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmmm, can't remember or find fitting function either.

There is [`wp_set_object_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) that is used in multiple wrappers like [`wp_set_post_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_categories). It can overwrite categories for a post.

So you can get post categories, check for unwanted one and write it back excluding unwanted in that case.

Comment: This is the best solution so far, and the one I will probably use. get_object_terms() to fetch, unset() the one I don't want, then wp_set_object_terms() to re-save the array. Too bad there's no wp_set_object_term() and wp_remove_object_term().

Comment: This is how I've done it in the past. It's pretty clunky and rife for improvement, but I believe it to be the best pattern avail.

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative to wp_set_object_terms is [wp_set_post_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_terms/) if you are dealing with a post object. It has a Boolean 4th parameter that lets you decide whether you will merely add terms or overwrite the existing ones.